# How to convert a string to a date in sybase

Tags: sybase, type-conversion

I need to specify a date value in a sybase where clause. For example:

```
select * 
from data
where dateVal < [THE DATE]
```

Answer (score 26):

Use the convert function, for example:

```
select * from data 
where dateVal < convert(datetime, '01/01/2008', 103)
```

Where the convert style (103) determines the date format to use.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a good reference on the different formatting you can use with regard to the date:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1510/html/iqrefbb/Convert.htm

Comment: Supplied Link is dead.

Answer (score 4):

Several ways to accomplish that but be aware that your DB **date_format option** & **date_order option** settings could affect the incoming format:

```
Select 
   cast('2008-09-16' as date)
   convert(date,'16/09/2008',103)
   date('2008-09-16')
from dummy;
```

Answer (score -1):

102 is the rule of thumb,
convert (varchar, creat_tms, 102) > '2011'