# Sybase: converting string to datetime

Tags: sybase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert a string to a date in sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56303/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-sybase)

How would you convert a string like '2008-01-01 11:09:11' to a datetime ?
The string is from outside of Sybase and I want to know how to insert it as a datetime

Answer (score 0):

Sybase supports a number of default formats to get the data into a datetime column.  Here is [a website](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/25357;hf=0) to list the many formats.